# GRPC cannot add data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, microservices, grpc

I use gRPC for communucation between microservices in asp.net app. I have to insert data in db with information from another micorservice. When I call repository to insert data in grpc server I got error. An error occurs when I call SaveChangesAsync() function.

Code for calling repository:

```
        public override async Task<AddAdditionalAbsenceResponse> AddAbsence(GrpcAbsenceCreateModelRequest request, ServerCallContext serverCallContext)
    {
        var response = new AddAdditionalAbsenceResponse();
        response.Message = await AddAbsenceResult(request);

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<string> AddAbsenceResult(GrpcAbsenceCreateModelRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var dateFrom = new DateTime(
                request.DateFrom.Year,
                request.DateFrom.Month,
                request.DateFrom.Day,
                request.DateFrom.Hours,
                request.DateFrom.Minutes,
                request.DateFrom.Seconds
            );

            var dateTo = dateFrom;

            AbsenceCreateDto absenceCreateDto = new AbsenceCreateDto()
            {
                Year = request.Year,
                Days = request.Days,
                AbsenceCode = request.AbsenceCode,
                DaysFromVacationThisYear = request.DaysFromVacationThisYear,
                DaysFromVacationLastYear = request.DaysFromVacationLastYear,
                DaysFromAdditionalAbsences = request.DaysFromAdditionalAbsences,
                Status = request.Status,
                DateFrom = dateFrom,
                DateTo = dateTo,
                UserId = request.UserId
            };

            var absence = _mapper.Map<Absences>(absenceCreateDto);
            var addAbsence = await _absenceRepository.AddAbsence(absence);

            return (addAbsence == null) ? "" : "added";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

function for inserting data:

```
 public async Task<Absences> AddAbsence(Absences absences)
    {
        if (absences == null) return null;

        _context.Add(absences);           
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return absences;
    }
```

ERROR message:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (30,062ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p2='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p3='?' (DbType = Int32), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (DbType = Int32), @p6='?' (DbType = Int32), @p7='?' (DbType = Int32), @p8='?' (Size = 450), @p9='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Absences] ([AbsenceCode], [DateFrom], [DateTo], [Days], [DaysFromAdditionalAbsences], [DaysFromVacationLastYear], [DaysFromVacationThisYear], [Status], [UserId], [Year])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [Absences]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.7\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update: Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'ManagementHub.Shared.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Comment: Yes, I'm calling this repository for another function and everything's working okay. So, everything with DB connection is okay

Comment: It doesn't say it can't communicate. It says there's a timeout, read the innermost exception: `Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`. If you execute the same command and same parameters against the database manually using SQL Server Management Studio, how long does it take to run?

Comment: With the same parameters in Management studio ela[sed time is 00:00:00.021